# Disable all page-zooming in IE11 on Windows8-Arm

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tablet

How can I disable ALL viewport zooming for a webpage accessed via IE11 on WinRT?

I'm working on an application that does it's own drawing on a canvas sized to fit the viewport, and provides it's own zoom functionality internally. Having the browser zoom then makes a mess of the canvas.

I've been going through existing answers, and none of them seem to work for this plaform:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>`
or
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">`
or
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`
or
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />`
or
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

In the `<header>` all have no effect.

Additionally, I'd like to block double-tap-zooming, but the various jQuery snippets I've seen don't seem to work here either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Arrrgh, so as soon as I asked the question, I found a solution:

Adding:

```css
html
{
    -ms-content-zooming: none; /* Disables zooming */
    touch-action: none;   /* Disable any special actions on tap/touch */
}
```

to the CSS for the application page appears to properly block pinch-zoom in IE, and disable any of the special actions triggered by tapping/double-tapping.

Comment: OMG this works. It was so hard to found how to block the user zoom for my cordova windows (phone) 10 app (that use Microsoft Edge engine). Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
var zoomlevel=1;

    $("body").dblclick(function(ev) {
        zoomlevel = zoomlevel == 1 ? 2 : 1;



        $(this).css({
            "-moz-transform":"scale("+zoomlevel+")",
            "-webkit-transform":"scale("+zoomlevel+")",
            "-o-transform":"scale("+zoomlevel+")",
            "-ms-transform":"scale("+zoomlevel+")"
        });


    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work. IE is weird. The only thing that does seem to work is the css `-ms-content-zooming: none; touch-action: none;` as in my answer.