# Touch gestures using the Edge browser and the Autodesk Viewer

Tags: touch, autodesk-viewer

Is there a way to enable touch support in the Microsoft Edge browser, similar to Google's Chrome browser?

Currently, if I pinch to zoom the entire page is zoomed in Edge, whereas only the model is zoomed in Chrome.

Comment: http://lmv.rocks/ exhibits the same behavior with regards to touch and Edge/IE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify "user-scalable=no" as meta-tag in your html page head section. That should fix it, otherwise that an Edge issue for the MS guys I would say ...

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimal-ui, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>"Viewer"</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Philippe.  Unfortunately, adding these tags doesn't fix the issue.
I wonder if it somehow related to this thread that I posted some time ago: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1822

Comment: It seems an Edge issue to me, all other browsers behave nicely when using the user-scalable=no meta-tag, I don't think it has anything to do with the js code running in the page ...

Comment: If what I am hearing you say is that this functionality isn't supported by Autodesk in the Edge and IE browsers, then it seems that the Viewer may have limited reach in the enterprise.

Comment: Seems that we are back the good old IE days :) ... I'm saying that if Edge is not respecting the "user-scalable=no" meta-tag, it's an Edge issue > that has to be addressed by Microsoft folks, not much Autodesk and the viewer team can do about it... Do you reproduce this behavior with any webpage or is it specific to the viewer?

Comment: I am able to use the touch gestures in Chrome without the user-scalable="no" meta-tag.  This doesn't seem to affect Chrome. From the looks of http://lmv.rocks/, they don't use that tag either.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

I was able to improve the behavior of pinch/zoom on touch screen with Edge using this css:

```
html .adsk-viewing-viewer{
    -ms-content-zooming: none; /* Disables zooming */
    touch-action: none;
}
```

from the answer: [Disable all page-zooming in IE11 on Windows8-Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757403/disable-all-page-zooming-in-ie11-on-windows8-arm)

The viewer pivots with finger gestures, but unfortunately doesn't zoom.  At least the entire page no longer zooms.