# Disable browser zoom in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, zooming

I want to disable zooming in IE11.
I found this line

```
<script>document.firstElementChild.style.zoom = "reset";</script>
```

doing what I really want but works only in chrome. Is there an alternative for IE11.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757403/disable-all-page-zooming-in-ie11-on-windows8-arm)?

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757403/disable-all-page-zooming-in-ie11-on-windows8-arm

Comment: Thanks both of you; but I don't mean disabling zoom after punch and select on mobile devices; I mean disabling zoom when using zoom-in zoom-out from toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

in the `<head>` section of your document to prevent scaling the website on mobile devices. Important here is `user-scalable=no` which makes the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in my case; the behavior I want is when zooming from browser toolbar, I want that the page doesn't change, I mean nothing happens.

Comment: Is there any way you can set the registry when page loads for disabling zoom and then enable zoom when your session ends? Look [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/86756-internet-explorer-zoom-enable-disable.html)

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773124/how-to-change-registry-settings-on-a-system-through-web-browser . I think it's impossible to do that.

Comment: Though it does say that it is only possible in IE :D

Comment: @Amirado I was reading at some places and there's no way you can control the application's (IE) feature using any script through the page unless somehow you gain access to registry or system settings.